# How to set up delayed jobs on Amazon EC2 for a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, delayed-job

When I need to set up the delayed job on Heroku, I need to buy there also the another worker dyno.
How does it work on Amazon EC2? I am using the small EC2 instance.

Do I need to buy a higher instance or what is needed for successful set up of delayed job on Amazon EC2?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

On EC2, you're basically buying infrastructure, so it basically depends on the workload that you're having if you need a higher instance or not. If you're not saturating the CPU on your current EC2 instance, all you have to do is use a gem like delayed_job (https://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job) or resque (https://rubygems.org/gems/resque). 
Personally, I didn't need a higher EC2 instance for delayed jobs, as they didn't use up a lot of resources (also small EC2).

Answer (score 1):

First of all welcome to delayed_job club. I agree with the previous answer, I was running delayed_job on a ec2 micro instance. But chances of delayed_job consuming more memory is high. I suggest you to have a separate instance for running delayed_jobs. Minimum a small instance would do. I am using https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job version of delayed since 2 years. Matured a lot over period. Quite stabilized compared to previous version. It also gives the web interface too.

Answer (score 1):

i have recently started using EC2(micro instance because its free and because i need a staging env) with delayed job for ActiveRecord. EC2 is same like a fresh machine with minimum configuration. You need to install all the necessary stuff like RVM, ruby, rubygems, git etc that you install on your local machine. I am using mina deployment and have specified there to manipulate nginx, passenger and delayed_job.

Comment: Anyone to explain how to set up delayed job gem on EC2 instance on ruby platform?